# How to switch locale on user's request? (When using the React-Redux-i18n library)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using the [React-Redux-i18n](https://github.com/zoover/react-redux-i18n) binding library for redux to translate my React app. 
I would also like to use React-Router to handle my routes.

I can get the example working, that is provided by React-Redux-i18n:

In app.js :

```
const translationsObject = {
  en: {
    application: {
      title: 'Awesome app with i18n!',
      hello: 'Hello, %{name}!'
    },
    date: {
      long: 'MMMM Do, YYYY'
    },
    export: 'Export %{count} items',
    export_0: 'Nothing to export',
    export_1: 'Export %{count} item',
    two_lines: 'Line 1<br />Line 2'
  },
  nl: {
    application: {
      title: 'Toffe app met i18n!',
      hello: 'Hallo, %{name}!'
    },
    date: {
      long: 'D MMMM YYYY'
    },
    export: 'Exporteer %{count} dingen',
    export_0: 'Niks te exporteren',
    export_1: 'Exporteer %{count} ding',
    two_lines: 'Regel 1<br />Regel 2'
  }
};

const store =  createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    i18n: i18nReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
syncTranslationWithStore(store)
store.dispatch(loadTranslations(translationsObject));
store.dispatch(setLocale('nl'));
```

Then I can use the following in my components, to translate strings:

```
<Translate value="application.title"/>
```

Language can be changed by changing the following from for example 'nl', to 'en':

```
store.dispatch(setLocale('nl'));
```

How can I enable user's to change the language. For example:

```
<a href="/" onClick={changeLanguage('nl')}>Nl</a>
<a href="/" onClick={changeLanguage('en')}>En</a>
```

How to change setLocale, when clicking the different language links?

Comment: what does `changeLanguage` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name `react-redux-i18n` suggests, it relies on `redux` to handle storing the i18n keys and values, i.e. they are stored in the `reducers`, specifically the `i18nReducer`, and the state of that reducer can be changed with `actions`, for example `dispatch(setLocale)`. If you aren't already familiar with Redux, I recommend getting to know the [basics](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/).

To create a link that changes your language you essentially need to find a way to `dispatch` a `setLocale` action to the redux store with the parameter of your choosing with the `onClick` handler. Redux provides a nifty way of doing this by [connecting](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) store state and dispatch method to your component. For example like this:

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'redux'
import { setLocale } from 'react-redux-i18n

class ChangeLanguageLink extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.changeLanguage = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault() // don't navigate
      this.props.changeLanguage(this.props.lang)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <a href="#" onClick={ this.changeLanguage }>
        { this.props.lang.toUpperCase() }
      </a>
    )
  }
}

ChangeLanguageLink.propTypes = {
  lang: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

// this will make this.props.changeLanguage available
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  // dispatch the react-redux-i18n setLocale action
  const changeLanguage = lang => dispatch(setLocale(lang))
  return { changeLanguage }
}

// using connect makes store.dispatch available for mapDispatchToProps
// and makes sure changeLanguage is added to the component props
@connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)
export class ChangeLanguageLinkContainer
extends ChangeLanguageLink {}
```

Then you can just utilize your language changing component like this:

```
<ChangeLanguageLink lang="en" />
<ChangeLanguageLink lang="nl" />

<!-- should produce html like this -->
<a href="#">EN</a>
<a href="#">NL</a>
```

Hope this helps!